# Performant API to handle many requests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am developing an iOS app to show news from a MongoDB database. The app has around 50,000 active users, so it's quite heavy on the server. I am trying to rethink how the API should be built. I have just learned a little about AWS API Gateway, Google Cloud Functions, Firebase, etc.

If I simply need a few functions to extract list of news, list of users, etc., what would be the best way to build this API as of 2017? I have always thought I should simply create a Node.js server with some endpoints. But now it seems it's more performant to create separate endpoints with, for instance, AWS API Gateway which each points to an AWS Lambda function.

But what is really the most scalable option?

Comment: Though a great question people might downvote it once it is not an specific programming question. Following anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront (With Caching) --> API Gateway --> Lambda would be a scalable solution. Since you have not chosen DynamoDB, you need to manage mongoose for your storage and avaibility.

To make it bit more advanced, you can use Lambda Edge with Cloudfront to make it active/active across more than one region. So if One region goes down, app will still be available.

Comment: You can enable caching inside API Gateway (which uses CloudFront behind the scenes). No need to place an extra CloudFront distribution in front of API Gateway just for caching.

Comment: Pricing between Cloudfront caching and API Caching varies. https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/  and  https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Performant", what does that mean in your scenario?

If you need a few functions that extract a list of news, a list of users and etc, it doesn't sound like performance would be an issue.

If you're wondering if the AWS Serverless Stack can handle thousands or millions of requests, the answer is yes, API Gateway + Lambda can handle requests at any scale.

If you only need to query data by its hash keys, DynamoDB would fit very well! Also, there's an [auto scale feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.html). But, if you need to perform scans or some complex queries, that would be a little bit expensive and some times slow. For this scenario you can stream your DynamoDB data to Elasticsearch or a data warehouse solution.

I'm not sure if combining Lambda with MongoDB would be that great. Let's say you choose a hosted MongoDB service like [Mongo Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas), you'll need to add more complexity to your system like VPC Peering, and also, manage/optmize lambda connections to MongoDB ([Optimizing AWS Lambda Performance with MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs)). What if you're handling a million request calls, I guess a lot of Lambda Functions will start running in parallel, how many connections would be opened in your MongoDB?

Besides the AWS Serverless Stack, there's the [Elastic BeansTalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) that can easily scale your system.

All the solutions have pros and cons, you can scale with both, API Gateway + Lambda or Elastic Beanstalk(or some other vendor solution). I guess "scalable" is a built in feature that cloud vendors are offering these days, and "performance" is just one of the topics that should be analyzed when designing your infrastructure.